# NoReverseMatch using {% url %}

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to follow the examples given here: [Refresh <div> element generated by a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583534/refresh-div-element-generated-by-a-django-template)

But I end up with:

```
NoReverseMatch at /search/: 
Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments 
'{u'flights':[{FLIGHTS}]}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []"
```

I see lots of search results for this error, but none of them seem relevant, unless I'm completely missing something.

Javascript in search.html: (UPDATED)

```
      <script>
        var flights = {{ flights | safe }}

        $.ajax({
        url: {% url 'search_results' flights %},
        success: function(data) {
        $('#search-results').html(data);
        }
        });
      </script>
```

views.py:

```
def search_results(request, flights):
    return render_to_response('search_results.html', flights)
```

urls.py: (UPDATED)

```
url(r'^search/search_results/(?P<flights>[^/]*)$', "fsApp.views.search_results", name='search_results'),
```

ETA:

I've now tried all of the following, and none work:

```
url(r'^search/(?P<flights>[^/]*)$', "fsApp.views.search_results", name='search_results'),                                                       
url(r'^search/search_results/(?P<flights>[^/]*)$', "fsApp.views.search_results", name='search_results'),
url(r'^search/(?P<flights>[^/]*)/search_results/$', "fsApp.views.search_results", name='search_results'),
```

Comment: The search_results URL does not take any parameters, but you are trying to pass it the value of "flights".

Comment: I've tried three different ways (based on responses and the documentation) and none of them work.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the url's name:

```
url(r'^search/(?P<flights>[^/]*)/search_results/$', "fsApp.views.search_results", name='search_results'),
```

In your template:

```
{% url 'search_results' flights as url_search %}

<script>
  ...
  url: '{{ url_search }}',
  ...
</script>
```

[Example from Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/#examples):

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #...
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive, name='news-year-archive'),
    #...
]
```

Comment: You current url definition is not expecting a `flights` param

Comment: @ballardjw2 I edited my answer, with an example to ask for a kwarg in your url, check docs linked in my answer to learn more.

Comment: The documentation seems to suggest it should just be "r'^search/(?P<flights>[^/]*)/$'"? Which also doesn't work. And another commenter reversed the flights and search_results parts and nope. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Yes. But "url(r'^search/(\[.*\])$', "fsApp.views.search_results", name='search_results')," works, sort of.

Comment: In your ajax: `'{% url 'search_results' flights %}'`. Don't miss `'`