# Fetch Django view data with AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-templates

Currently I am building an app which update the main page's data via AJAX.
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583534/refresh-div-element-generated-by-a-django-template) question I used (see code/1/ below) ajax to refresh my page. My other aim is to catch just certain variable from the view and use as a JS variable. If I use only Django template variable in the AJAX request my variable not refreshig.

**First attempt:**

**Django view:**

```
def fetch_data (request):

    query_1=Objects.all()
    query_2=Objects.all()

    #From these  queries I colect data and push  them to lists.

    context= {
                'variable_1': variable_1,
                'variable_2': variable_2,
                'time_variable': time_variable #changing in every minute
           }

    return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```

**AJAX:**

Here I use the AJAX request. I run it in every minute to realod my page my page. My problem is that I want to load just let's say the `time_variable` to use it again within AJAX. If I use it like a single template variable (`{{time_variale|safe}}`) when the AJAX reloading I get the same variable again and again and not a new one because of the refreshing. How gen I catch the Django variable?

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(new Date().getSeconds() === 0) {     
        $.ajax({
        url:'{% url 'fetch_data' %}',
        success: function (data){
              $('body').html(data); #This working, the data refreshing
              var="{{time_variable|safe}}"; #Here I always get the same in every minutes despite the variable get new value in every minute in the view.
           }
        });
  }
},1000)
```

Comment: I can't understand why you would think that a hard-coded value inside the JS itself would change as a result of the Ajax call.

Comment: This just was an idea and I shared it, I realized that, it not working. Do you know any suggestion?

Comment: `{{time_variable|safe}}` is calculated when the page is rendered, not when the javascript is run.  You need to pass the new time variable back with your json

Comment: You are calling AJAX request to refresh only a body of your html template, but it doesn't refresh your variable. In order to refresh variable as well, you can create another view that will return your variable in a JSON format. And then in your javascript part, you can create another AJAX request that will call JSON-view and get value of variable from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Fetch data from the server in JSON format and update the variable and HTML. A new view is needed to provide data to AJAX request.

```
    setInterval(function(){
    if(new Date().getSeconds() === 0) {     
        $.ajax({
        url:'{% url 'fetch_data' %}',
        success: function (data){
              response_json = JSON.parse(data)

              $('body').html(response_json.html_data); #This working, the data refreshing
              var=response_json.variable_value; #Here I always get the same in every minutes despite the variable get new value in every minute in the view.
           }
        });
    }
   },1000)
```

**Solution 2**

Reload the page in intervals, this not a recommended suggestion though as it just degrades performance of back-end and inefficient.