# How to make a request using jQuery to a django server to refresh infos on page

Tags: javascript, python, django, http, request

I made a website in python using Django. My site allows you to control lights while indicating if the light is on or not.
I'm looking for a solution that could make a simple request with data to the server and send data back to the client without updating the entire page but only a part of it.

My ideal would be for the client to make a request to the server with identification data. Then, the server returns the updated data that the user is allowed to have.

Is that possible to make a JavaScript to do that ? And the server, how it can return data to the client ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh <div> element generated by a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583534/refresh-div-element-generated-by-a-django-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use jquery AJAX for send request and get a response and Update an element or part of the page you can read more about it in :

[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

or :

[jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

AJAX function I use for PHP project:(Just for example)

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Url,
        data: InfoData, // data if you want to send for example InfoData={dataName: variable} or you can set this = '' if you don't want to send data
        datatype: "html",
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but how i can launch this code from a button for exemple ? Can i put that directly in my HTML code between <script>HERE</script>

Comment: you can launch it with javascript or jquery event like onclick="yourFunction()" or $("#your-button").click();

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp or https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp you can read these links and know how to launch it

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wzzYAmAP : Here is my code, but it does not work with a file name "demo_test.txt" as my page named "index.html"... What's wrong ?

Comment: I'm sorry, don't worry, i don't have any more problem thanks you